# playwright Mobile chrome view shows empty page because of which visual comparison fails

Tags: playwright

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlv7D.png)
Below is the code to compare snapshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Y9n.png)
My playwright config is as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELVU9.png)

Note the test works fine for Desktop. The expected page is not empty but actual page screenshot becomes empty. Also the application is up and running

Tried updating snapshots and rerun but not sure what the issue is for mobile view port

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Can you share a [mcve], please? Thanks.